# Image Flickering on high reolution image loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web application in which user can navigate to the next and previous images one by one which are placed in some location in file system.

I am having facing a problem while image loading.When a high resolution image is loaded to container it flickers and then renders.I am using onload event to ensure that image is completely loaded in this way:

```
        image.onload = function () {
            $('#img').attr('src', image.src);
        };
        image.src = imagePath;
```

To give a better user experience i am trying to load a low resolution image first so that it display immediately and then it fade out then the higher resolution image fade in when it is completely loaded.Low resolution image renders immediately but the high resolution image still flickers and then displayed on container.It is not looking smooth on image change.

How can I resolve this issue? Please provide some solution or idea that i can implement for better user experience.

Comment: www.jsfiddle.net demo would be great.

Comment: "Please provide some solution" Maybe but you cannot you provide a sample code or better a sample jsfiddle???

Comment: Would a progressive jpg work?  In most browsers, it performs the way you want, by loading lower resolution/less detailed versions and progressively getting more detailed as it loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
      image.onload = function () {
            $('#img').attr('src', image.src);
        };
        image.src = imagePath;
}, 5000);
```

you can use settimeout so that the flickering will not be visible to the user. This might not be the best solution. but it may fix ur issue